# Reading Encoded value in spark 1.6 throwing Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

I am receiving file from API which have a encoded(non-ascii) character value in 3 columns.
when i am reading file using DataFrame in Spark1.6

```
val CleanData= sqlContext.sql("""SELECT
                                               COL1
                                               COL2,
                                               COL3
                                               FROM CLEANFRAME
                                               """ )
```

Encoded value looks like below.

[image]

But encoded value appear like

53004, �����������������������������

May someone please help me how to fix this error if possiblw with spark 1.6 and scala.
**Spark 1.6,
scala**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#this ca be achieved by using the regex_replace
    val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("503004","d$üíõ$F|'.h*Ë!øì=(.î;      ,.¡|®!®","3-2-704"))).toDF("col1","col2","col3")
    df.withColumn("col2_new", regexp_replace($"col2", "[^a-zA-Z]", "")).show()    
Output:
+------+--------------------+-------+--------+
|  col1|                col2|   col3|col2_new|
+------+--------------------+-------+--------+
|503004|d$üíõ$F|'.h*Ë!øì=...|3-2-704|     dFh|
+------+--------------------+-------+--------+
```